# Synonymize [chars] with [character]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, synonym-request

[chars](/questions/tagged/chars) (100) and [character](/questions/tagged/character) (2k) seems to be used pretty interchangeably.

Should [chars](/questions/tagged/chars) be made a synonym of [character](/questions/tagged/character)?

Comment: And probably mix [tag:char] (3k) in there as well (plurals are usually synonyms in any way). Though I don't find these tags particularly descriptive (or at least largely misused).